# How to check if a file retrieved from the ftp site exists in the local folder in java using talend?

Tags: java, sql, string, oracle, talend

I am using FtpGet to extract or retrieve a file from the ftp and loading into the database and before that i am storing in a local folder.

So before i use tfilecopy to the local Folder i would like to perform a check wherein if the file already exists in the local folder skip or ignore the next steps,if they dont exist then only write (tfilecopy) to the local folder.

So basically i want to iterate through the list of files in the local folder based on the one i am retrieving using

GlobalMap variables:dynamically and check if that file exists or not amongst the list of all the other files in that folder and perform the action.

I Have created this in talend,i could either check the database to see if the file exists or directly check the local folder where there is a copy of the ftp files(if the same file already exists) skip the process.

Only if it does not exist write to the local folder.

Which is the best approach either to scan it in the internal folders(although there maybe sub-folders as well) by writing a tjava code

Or use database script to query and only if the filename does not exist in the table,copy that file onto a target folder and write to a db table.

[image: Talend]

So primarily i am iterating through the current file from tfilelist3 and checking if they exist in tfilelist2 component using TJAVA and tfilecopy only if the file retrieved does not exist in tfilelist_2

TJAVA:

```
String  path =((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_2_CURRENT_FILEDIRECTORY"));

 System.out.println("PRINTING PATH in string: " +path);
 
 Path filepath=Paths.get(path);

  System.out.println("PRINTING PATH in PATH: " +filepath);
 
String  fileName =((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_3_CURRENT_FILE"));

 System.out.println("PRINTING FILENAME IN STRING: " +fileName); 
 
 File file = new File(fileName);
 System.out.println("File is " +file);
 

//File f = new File(path);
if(file.exists()) 
{
 System.out.println("Filename: "+file); //+ path.toString());
             System.out.println("Exist in location!");
 //  System.out.println("File EXIST " +f);
} else 
{
      System.out.println("Filename: "+file); //+ path.toString());
            System.out.println("Does not exist in location!");
}
```

I kinda made it little complex and i am lost now,would be great if someone could fix the remaining part and make it work,i cant seem to find a way through this maze now !
I had tried different versions and none of the seem to produce the result that i am looking for?

So file.exists() only checks for the specific file in the current directory,so what if i need to check in a different directory,how do i pass the arguments?

Approach 2 :
[image: check if file exists in a different folder before copying to desination/target]

Answer (score 2):

You can create a java routine eg:

```
findFile("fileName","FilePath")
```

Invoke the routine for each file by passing the `fileName` and `filePath` as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check tFileExist component ? It seems that it could be useful (only parameter is folder+filename you want to check ).

Comment: Yes i checked it but the problem is it gives an option only to look for in a particular filepath,but in my case i would want to fetch a file from different folder and scan for them if they exist in a different folder,so tfilexist component wont take 2 parameters,that is the problem here

Comment: Sorry I don't get it exactly : let's say your original file is FolderA/FileA : you can use tFileExists and set the parameter to check if FolderB/FileA exists (using concatenation of  your variable containing FolderB and tFileList_3.CURRENT_FILE).  Wouldn't this be sufficient ?

Comment: I am kind of getting you partially but not all the way,i tried with different approaches it wont work,I added an approach 2 image to the question itself -can you please take a look and suggest if i need to chip in a tjava component before tfileexist to concatenate variable containing folderb and filename from folder A?Lets say i am reading the file tfilelist1 and want to check if the same filename exists in tfilelist2 before writing/copying onto the target folder...i hope now it makes much sense to understand what i am trying to achieve,Please let me know,appreciate your insights :)

Comment: Is the folder from tFileList_2 a Fixed Value ? If so you can put it in your tFileExist and concatenate filename from tFilelist_1 : "C:/temp/tFileList2Folder/"+((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")) . Then your tFileExist component will be able to check for each file in your tFileList_1 if this file exists in the repository tFileList_2.

Comment: Okay i got it now,appreciate it...so i was wondering if i could even scan the subdirectories or subfolder within tfielist2folder? Lets say we have several sub-dir within it and the file exist could anywhere within that,i want to make sure they dont exist even inside the sub folders of tfilelist2folder?Do i have to create a tjava component and parse as a variable in tfilexist condition?

Comment: Place tFileList_2 before tFileExists (so iterate link before AND after tFileList_2), configure it to scan only repositories (not file). Your __DIRECTORY__ variable in tFileList_2 should be your current tFileList_1 currentFilePath. Then on the tFileExists, check for the file in your current tFileList_2 repository (you should access the variable through tFileList_2_CURRENT_FILEPATH)